# How to set a base URL to use a specific GET request URL for that page

Tags: javascript, json, get

I'm trying to get data from a page specific GET request.

The base URL would be for example https://example.com/pages/subpage

Using the console on that page it gives me GET data that is only available to that specific page.

Can I set a base URL and the GET URL when using getJSON?

```
getJSON('https://api.example.com/api/pagedata', function(err, response) { }
```

More clarification:
https://example.com/pages/subpage1, https://example.com/pages/subpage2 and https://example.com/pages/subpage3 all got the same GET URL in the API (https://api.example.com/api/pagedata) but the response data will have different values depending on what subpage you are on.

Comment: what you mean "base url" and difference to get url?

Comment: getting the specific https://api.example.com/api/pagedata from the URL https://example.com/pages/subpage

Comment: If I understand you want to call base url which return you url for getting data?

Comment: yes, and i added more clarification

Answer (score 0):

you have url A,B & C then you can use same GET URL by using parameters.
e.g.

In javascript :

```
var page = "A";
getJSON('https://api.example.com/api/pagedata?current_page='+page, function(err, response) { }
```

NOTE: set variable page according to pagename

In PHP :

```
  <?php

    $current_page = $_GET["current_page"];

    if($current_page=='A'){
      // your code here for page A
    }else if($current_page=='B'){
    // your code here for page B
    } else if($current_page=='C'){
    // your code here for page C
    }
?>
```

HAPPY CODING :-)